# Typescript HttpClient.post returning bad request from json formatted string

Tags: json, typescript, rest

Ok I have been manipulating this string for hours! So any help is greatly appreciated

I am trying to simply make a post call and generate a password. The api is setup to take in a string a parses the json formatted string itself.

```
private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    var url: string = 'https://eus-safeaccounts-test.azurewebsites.net/' + 'passwords/generate';
    var body: string = '"{\"regex\":\"[a-zA-Z0-9]\",\"minLength\":8,\"maxLength\":12}"';

    http.post<string>(url, body, { headers: this.headers }).subscribe(result => {
      this.signUpResponseStr = result["password"];
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

This call returns code 400 bad request. (I think because the text is not being seen as json?)

However, if we set `body = '""';` then we get a password sent back from the api  no problem. It is seen as an empty string on API side and then they give us a password. Exploring further I tried setting `body = '"abc"';` because that is a string not following json format. In this case, we DO NOT get bad request 400, but the api recognizes bad json format and returns `Invalid Json`

**My Question:**

What should the body string look like for me to send this request? The API is open so anyone can reproduce and the API code shouldn't have anything to do with the 400 bad request issue, as we can see from my explorations, but the code is here https://github.com/nickpavini/SafeAccountsAPI.

Thanks for any help! :)

**EDIT:** I also tried sending as `JSON` type and I also tried `JSON.stringify()` with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The string is a bit tricky to understand but hopefully this will help others.

```
body = '"{\\"regex\\":\\"[a-zA-Z0-9]\\",\\"minLength\\":8,\\"maxLength\\":12}"'
```

In this case it seems that the body contains a string. (the actual string that will be received by the server)

Inside that string, whenever we need the server to see a `"` that does not close the string, we must pass an actual backslash `\\` and then a `"`. We do not need 3 backslashes in this case because the single quote `'` at the beginning makes sure all paranthesis are included.

**Note:** Test this with the api in question if it seems weird to you. I think it has to do with the api implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Probably body should not be double quoted, and should look instead like...

```
var body: string = '{"regex":"[a-zA-Z0-9]","minLength":8,"maxLength":12}'
```

Comment: Its not that either. That was the first thing i tried. Adding double quoutes was only this to make it go through as empty string